# How to update C# from 9.0 to 11.0?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I want to use required here, but I get error that I need C# 11.0

```
using Microsoft.Build.Framework;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class BackendClient
{
    public required string url { get; set; }
    public string appId;
    public string deviceId;
 
    public BackendClient(string url, string appId, string deviceId)
    {
        this.url = url;
        this.appId = appId;
        this.deviceId = deviceId;
    }
 
    public List<Category> getCategories()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have Mircrosoft Visual Studio version 17.7.2, .Net Framework version 4.8.09032, but in Assembly-CSharp i have this version of C#

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I changed it on this

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <LangVersion Condition="'$(MSBuildProjectExtension)'=='.csproj'">preview</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And after previous this

```
<LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>
```

But after starting the unity project with code or assembly in visual studio it returns to 9.0 version. How can i change version to 11.0?

Comment: has unity announced c# 11 is supported? I must have missed that.

Comment: Care to also share the actual error you get?

Comment: I've tested new lines in assembly, error with 11.0 version c# left after i added <PropertyGroup> <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion> </PropertyGroup>, but now i get error - missing compiler required member 'system.runtime.compilerservices.required member attribute..ctor' on this line - public class BackendClient

Comment: Unity uses `c# 9.0` (https://docs.unity3d.com/2023.2/Documentation/Manual/CSharpCompiler.html) you can't simply change the version ... can you really no live without `required` .. it seems kinda redundant to me as you anyway only have one constructor which requires it as parameter ...

Comment: Beyond this being Unity specific, C# 11 is locked to .NET 7.0, (which is .NET Core) *not* .NET Framework. .NET Framework is going to be stuck on 4.8.x until its death in a decade, so the max you'll have is C# 9

Comment: The latest C# compilers determine the default language version based on one or more of the project's target frameworks. Visual Studio doesn't provide a UI to change the value, but you can change the value by editing the .csproj file.

So when you change <LangVersion> you also need to change the target framework of the project.

Comment: But C#11 is only supported on .NET 7 and above. So if you change your target framework to .net 7, but the .net framework project cannot simply change its target framework to .net 7.0, otherwise it will cause endless errors in the project.

What's more, Unity doesn't seem to support .net 7.0 yet




For details, please refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version